# Как можно объединить значения разных строк sql

Tags: sql, group-by

В таблице имеются записи такого вида

```
id    attr_id  lang_id  text
6829  61       1        'Для мужчин'
6829  61       1        'Для детей'
6829  61       1        'Для женщин'
```

Как можно сделать выборку из базы сведя 3 эти строчки в одну по полю attr_id
что бы получилось так

(6829, 61, 1, 'Для мужчин, Для детей, Для женщин'),

Если использовать в запросу `GROUP BY attr_id` то в поле `text` запишется только первое значение.

Comment: Укажите для какой СУБД нужно решение. Конкатенация по разному реализуется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ зависит от используемой СУБД.

Например, для MySQL запрос может выглядеть так:

```
SELECT id, attr_id, lang_id, GROUP_CONCAT(text)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id, attr_id, lang_id
```

Comment: супер спасибо все работает)